# Cделать return из Response okHttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Всем привет. Не могу вернуть значения из Response.
Так вызываю функцию:

```
Connection ClassConnect = new Connection();
ClassConnect.SendData("asdasd");
```

Код класса:

```
public class Connection {
    public void SendData(String InputData) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "http://192.168.0.11:5000/";
        String json = InputData;
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                //return ошибку
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    //return myResponse; вернуть ответ с сервера
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Что делать? Подскажите...

Comment: Я в подобном случае (с использованием AsyncTask) добавлял интерфейс, таким образом при создании класса Connection мы передаем интерфейс тем самым определяем что делать с полученным ответом. А в самом классе Connection в onResponse мы вызываем функцию и передаем response.body().string();

Answer (score 2):

Значение оттуда не получится вернуть, т.к. оно получено асинхронно и обработать его можно либо внутри тела функции:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) { 
    /* вот здесь */
}
```

Либо в другой фукнции, куда ваше значение будет передано как параметр:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) { 
    someFunction(response); // вот так
}
```

Иначе никак. Поищите информацию насчёт асинхронности, переписывать любую из статей, которых много в интернете, я не стану.

Значение можно получить синхронно, вызвав `execute` вместо `enqueue`:

```
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Но тогда делать это придётся в другом потоке.

Answer (score 0):

На вашем месте, я добавил бы в метод `SendData` *callback-listener*. Например такой:

```
public interface RequestListener {
    void doResponse(Response response);
    void doErrorMessage(String errorMessage);
}
```

Тогда, во-первых метод отправки запроса останется универсальным, а во-вторых  обработка результатов различных запросов будет происходить снаружи. Я бы привел более подробный пример, с использованием, но проект комерческий, поэтому из головы приведу только пример интерфейса и теоретическое описание.

Answer (score 0):

Вернуть значение можно с помощью слушателя, используя интерфейс. Так же обращаю ваше внимание на то, что в старших версиях Android API запрещено работать с интернет соединениями из UI потока SendData() необходимо выполнять в отдельном потоке.

Привожу самый простой пример:

1. Создайте в вашем классе интерфейс. Реализуйте в нем два метода (метод ошибки и метод результата);
2. Создайте в вашем классе статический абстрактный класс, который унаследует этот интерфейс.(это поможет создавать экземпляры слушателя, реализуя в них только необходимые методы, а не все методы интерфейса);
3. Во время вызова метода, передавайте ему слушателя.

Код вашего класс:

```
public class Connection {
 public interface SendDataListenerInterface {
     void onError(IOException e);
     void onResult(String value);
 }
public abstract static class  SendDataListener implements SendDataListenerInterface {
    @Override
    public void onError(IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(String value) {

    }
}

public void SendData(final String InputData, final SendDataListenerInterface listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            String url = "http://192.168.0.11:5000/";
            String json = InputData;
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    listener.onError(e); // вернет результат ошибки
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String myResponse = response.body().string();
                        listener.onResult(myResponse); // вернет результат выполнения
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Используйте ваш класс следующим способом:

```
Connection ClassConnect = new Connection();
    Connection.SendDataListener ClassListener = new Connection.SendDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(String value) {
            Log.d("RETURN DATA", value); // Выводим в logcat вернувшийся результат
        }
    };        
    ClassConnect.SendData("data_text", ClassListener);
```